# Ошибка в результате отправки запроса на север retrofit + rxjava. Error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c203",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c204",
                "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c205",
                "name": "Dido",
                "email": "dido@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c206",
                "name": "Adele",
                "email": "adele@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c207",
                "name": "Hugh Jackman",
                "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c208",
                "name": "Will Smith",
                "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c209",
                "name": "Clint Eastwood",
                "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2010",
                "name": "Barack Obama",
                "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2011",
                "name": "Kate Winslet",
                "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2012",
                "name": "Eminem",
                "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.Toast;


        import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;

        import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
        import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
        import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
        import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
        import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
        import retrofit2.Retrofit;
        import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.androidhive.info/";

            private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

            private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;

            private DataAdapter mAdapter;

            private ArrayList<Example> mAndroidArrayList;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
                initRecyclerView();
                loadJSON();
            }

            private void initRecyclerView() {

                mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            }

            private void loadJSON() {


                RequestInterface requestInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build().create(RequestInterface.class);

                mCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.register()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));


            }




            private void handleResponse(List<Example> androidList) {

                mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>(androidList);
                mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            private void handleError(Throwable error) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("ca", "Error "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                mCompositeDisposable.clear();
            }
        }




        package com.example.kostya.textto;

        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


        public class Example {

            @SerializedName("contacts")
            @Expose
            private List<Android> contacts;

            public List<Android> getContacts() {
                return contacts;
            }

            public void setContacts(List<Android> contacts) {
                this.contacts = contacts;
            }
        }



        package com.example.kostya.textto;

        import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


        public class Android {
            @SerializedName("id")
            @Expose
            private String id;
            @SerializedName("name")
            @Expose
            private String name;
            @SerializedName("email")
            @Expose
            private String email;
            @SerializedName("address")
            @Expose
            private String address;
            @SerializedName("gender")
            @Expose
            private String gender;
            @SerializedName("phone")
            @Expose
            private Phone phone;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }

            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            public String getGender() {
                return gender;
            }

            public void setGender(String gender) {
                this.gender = gender;
            }

            public Phone getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }

            public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }

        }



    package com.example.kostya.textto;

    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;



    public class Phone {

        @SerializedName("mobile")
        @Expose
        private String mobile;
        @SerializedName("home")
        @Expose
        private String home;
        @SerializedName("office")
        @Expose
        private String office;

        public String getMobile() {
            return mobile;
        }

        public void setMobile(String mobile) {
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }

        public String getHome() {
            return home;
        }

        public void setHome(String home) {
            this.home = home;
        }

        public String getOffice() {
            return office;
        }

        public void setOffice(String office) {
            this.office = office;
        }
    }


    package com.example.kostya.textto;

            import java.util.List;

            import io.reactivex.Observable;
            import retrofit2.http.GET;


    public interface RequestInterface {
        @GET("contacts/")
        Observable<List<Example>> register();

    }
```

Comment: А в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb, вопрос прост: "Кто виноват и что делать?" =) Ответ - в ответе

Answer (score 0):

У вас всего один объект в теле ответа, в коем лежит массив других объектов. Вы же говорите ретрофиту, что хотите массив объектов типа `Example`, вместо одного. Т.е. сделайте так:

```
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("contacts/")
    //Observable<List<Example>> register();
    Observable<Example> register();

}
```